# Why does importing a Python library throw a syntax error?

Tags: python, syntax-error, jython, python-importlib, wlst

I have a Windows machine in which some Python code works, but now needs to work on new machine.

I have installed the same Python version 3.6.5.

First issue was that when I run the code, it ***can not*** find a `re.py` library, which is in fact in Python's Lib folder. So I have added `sys.path.append('C:\Python\Lib')` and now it can find it.

But now I get the syntax error from that library, where I say `import re`, that lines throws an error regarding some line in re.py library. If I import `getopt`, I also get syntax error on some line.

How is that even possible? Syntax error in pythons Lib files which came with installation?

And the thing is that on machine 1 it works, same file contents, same python version. I am under impression that I have wrong in `python.exe` version for this version of libraries, but I have simply downloaded Windows installer and installed it.

I don't even know what to google for, does someone has any idea? I am importing re in `WeblogicAuto.py` on line 5.

```
D:\Jenkins\workspace\weblogic-full-deployment-copy\weblogic-deployment>MainAutoDeployment.py -f DEV -v 2.61.0.12 

Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

Type help() for help on available commands

Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "D:\Jenkins\workspace\weblogic-full-deployment-copy\weblogic-deployment\WeblogicAuto.py", line 5, in ?
  File "C:\Python\Lib\re.py", line 247
        b"_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890")
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Are you using the same python version on both machines?

Comment: I suggest you install and use python virtual environment. That way, you specify the packages and specific versions you want in a requirements.txt file.

Comment: Use pip freeze in one machine and install those on another

Comment: version is the same when I type python --version, but what is weird that machine 1 has only py launcher installed, while it has full C:\Python folder. I am new sys admin and trying to reverse engineer, no one here to knowledge transfer to me. I am new to python but not new to programming languages, I may try this pip freeze, I have tried to copy whole folder from one machine to other, and to pip install all stuff from pip list

Comment: The error message pretty clearly indicates that what you are running is not a current version of Python 3. The `b"..."` byte string syntax was introduced in Python 3.0 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3112/), though it should work (but no-op) in Python 2.7

Comment: yes it does seems so as I said, but python version is 3.6.5 and on this machine it never had version 2.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK many thanks to ya all, I've found the solution, it was about Jython libraries. I will try to elaborate a bit if someone stumbles upon this issue.

What I do here is that I deploy java modules to Oracle Weblogic application server. So this answer will also help someone trying to deploy to Weblogic from python.

From the start I was avoiding to install Webloglogic software on a machine from where I do the deploy (and that is a Jenkins slave which runs these python file, simple job).
I noticed that first machine (first Jenkins slave) has Weblogic installed, but I like to keep it minimal :)

What you do need is weblogic.jar and (not sure at this moment) wlfullclient.jar which is generated on Weblogic server (google how if needed or you may already have it).

The thing is that even though I have pure python code, when you call another python code with **java weblogic.WLST pythonCode.py**, it will be run with jython application! And it needs its libraries in its sys path.

In jython file I've added print(sys.path) then run in on both machines (slaves). I've noticed that path is different on those machines, even though if you type it in command prompt you get the same, but different then when Jenkins runs it.

So instead of looking how to fix those paths and copy files to them, I have created folders where it expects them, and copied them from first machine (easy fix, I may look into it later).

These are the sys.path and files that were needed, present on first machine:

```
['D:\\Jenkins\\weblogic\\Lib', '__classpath__', 'C:/bea10/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar', 'C:/bea10/wlserver_10.3/common/wlst/modules/jython-modules.jar/Lib', 'C:/bea10/wlserver_10.3/common/wlst', 'C:/bea10/wlserver_10.3/common/wlst/lib', 'C:/bea10/wlserver_10.3/common/wlst/modules', '.']
```

This was sys.path on second machine, so I simply copied there:

```
['D:\\Jenkins\\weblogic\\Lib', '__classpath__', 'D:/Jenkins/server/lib/weblogic.jar', 'D:/Jenkins/common/wlst/modules/jython-modules.jar/Lib', 'D:/Jenkins/common/wlst', 'D:/Jenkins/common/wlst/lib', 'D:/Jenkins/common/wlst/modules', '.']
```

Note that jython-modules.jar is a file, so /Lib should be from that file if I get how java works.

Feel free to contact me for more details.

Comment: Nice! Never be afraid to answer your own question!

Answer (score 2):

You are using WLST (WebLogic Scripting Tool).

WLST is very specific distribution of python:

- it's jython
- it roughly corresponds with python 2.7

And you trying to import libs from your CPython 3.6.5 distribution.

You need to:

- remove your `sys.path.append` that you added earlier
- check python libraries in jython library path. Which could be `$HOME/.jython` or WLST-specific path (look in WebLogic documentation)

Comment: I have jython on both machines, folder contents seems the same. What should I exactly do by "check python libraries in jython library path"?

Comment: I think I found it, I was printing sys.path from code on both machines, and on non-working one I have some stuff which does not exist, I will fix this and let you guys know tomorrow

Comment: @IgorIgorito you must be on right track. Check not only libs but interpreter too: don't try to execute WLST scripts by CPython or vice versa. WebLogic uses jython (not CPython) because it needs JVM-specific features.

Comment: thanks man, it works, I've just wrote an answer if someone needs it